# No source maps files in release mode

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, typescript

I'm deploying an Angular application using ASP.NET MVC and Typescript. We use FinalBuilder and  MSBuild. We are using Typescript 1.0 and the .js and .js.map-files are not included in the project. When we build only the js files are generated but they include a reference to the source map files like this:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=App.js.map
```

This causes Chrome Developer Tools to report a 404 for the .map files since they are never generated by MSBuild.

Is there a way not to generate source maps in release mode but only in debug mode?

We are using VS2013 and MSBuild 12.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Visual Studio "TypeScript Build" section has a checkbox for "Generate source maps" that is tied to the build configuration.  Also tsc has the --sourcemap parameter that you can either include (to generate) or exclude (to not).  Most node-based builders (such as grunt-ts) also have this functionality via the config json file.  Any of these options should cover you.

That said, source maps aren't requested by the browser unless you have the dev tools open anyway, so this isn't actually a problem for normal users.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the "Generate source maps" checkbox. I do want to keep generating source map files in debug mode. We use MSBuild - in our build automation software - to build the solution and hence don't explicitly use tsc. Perhaps there is a way to tell MSBuild not to generate map files in release mode. An MSBuild target?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're actually getting the source maps, but if it's via the Visual Studio compile on save functionality, then the generate source maps checkbox is per-build configuration; therefore you can have it enabled for debug but disabled for release configuration.

Comment: Per-build configuration of course! Thank you! This was exactly was I was looking for. Now the source map files get generated when I debug but not when I publish. I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: What exactly did you add (and where) to prevent including map files on publish? Like you, I want it on debug but not in publish.